# What does the flashing red alert mean?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys-3

Sometimes during gameplay a red light flashes with an alarm. I can't tell what triggers it, and what makes it go away.

So what does the flashing red alert mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A flashing red alert means that your air ventilation is off and needs to be started in order to get the air back to normal.

This is an indicator to let you know that if you do not fix the air ventilation you will start to see more hallucinations.